Issue with Hard Disk Functionality on Raspberry Pi 5
We have been using a hard disk for continuous video recording on our Raspberry Pi 5 (8GB RAM) for more than a week.
However, after a power restart or reboot of the same device, the hard disk is not functioning or getting detected. Interestingly, the hard disk resumes normal functionality when it is connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 once and then reconnected to the Raspberry Pi 5.

We have ruled out power-related issues, as the hard disk is provided with external power, yet it fails to be detected on the Raspberry Pi 5.
Please advise on potential resolutions or further steps to address this issue.

If you rely on the buggy automount "feature" expect problems. It doesn't mount a drive in the same place twice. Use a properly configured /etc/fstab entry and preferably disable the File Manager "feature".
